# C# RawInputDevice in Windows: How I can disable messages for all applications except my?

Tags: c#, winapi, raw-input

I have a RawInputDevice that I registered.

```
// sample
private void SplashLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var rid = new RawInputDevice[1];
            rid[0].UsagePage = HidUsagePage.GENERIC;
            rid[0].Usage = HidUsage.Keyboard;
            rid[0].Flags = RawInputDeviceFlags.INPUTSINK;
            rid[0].Target = Handle;
            if (!Win32.RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, (uint)rid.Length, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(rid[0])))
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Не удалось зарегистрировать устройство.");
            }
            inputBuffer = "";
            this.terminateFlag = false;
            t = new Thread(MainThread);
            t.Start(this);
        }
// another cs file goes there
    internal enum RawInputDeviceFlags
        {
            /// <summary>No flags.</summary>
            NONE = 0,
            /// <summary>If set, this removes the top level collection from the inclusion list. This tells the operating system to stop reading from a device which matches the top level collection.</summary>
            REMOVE = 0x00000001,
            /// <summary>If set, this specifies the top level collections to exclude when reading a complete usage page. This flag only affects a TLC whose usage page is already specified with PageOnly.</summary>
            EXCLUDE = 0x00000010,
            /// <summary>If set, this specifies all devices whose top level collection is from the specified UsagePage. Note that Usage must be zero. To exclude a particular top level collection, use Exclude.</summary>
            PAGEONLY = 0x00000020,
            /// <summary>If set, this prevents any devices specified by UsagePage or Usage from generating legacy messages. This is only for the mouse and keyboard.</summary>
            NOLEGACY = 0x00000030,
            /// <summary>If set, this enables the caller to receive the input even when the caller is not in the foreground. Note that WindowHandle must be specified.</summary>
            INPUTSINK = 0x00000100,
            /// <summary>If set, the mouse button click does not activate the other window.</summary>
            CAPTUREMOUSE = 0x00000200,
            /// <summary>If set, the application-defined keyboard device hotkeys are not handled. However, the system hotkeys; for example, ALT+TAB and CTRL+ALT+DEL, are still handled. By default, all keyboard hotkeys are handled. NoHotKeys can be specified even if NoLegacy is not specified and WindowHandle is NULL.</summary>
            NOHOTKEYS = 0x00000200,
            /// <summary>If set, application keys are handled.  NoLegacy must be specified.  Keyboard only.</summary>
            APPKEYS = 0x00000400,
            /// If set, this enables the caller to receive input in the background only if the foreground application
            /// does not process it. In other words, if the foreground application is not registered for raw input,
            /// then the background application that is registered will receive the input.
            /// </summary>
            EXINPUTSINK = 0x00001000,
            DEVNOTIFY = 0x00002000
        }

        public enum HidUsagePage : ushort
        {
            /// <summary>Unknown usage page.</summary>
            UNDEFINED = 0x00,
            /// <summary>Generic desktop controls.</summary>
            GENERIC = 0x01,
            /// <summary>Simulation controls.</summary>
            SIMULATION = 0x02,
            /// <summary>Virtual reality controls.</summary>
            VR = 0x03,
            /// <summary>Sports controls.</summary>
            SPORT = 0x04,
            /// <summary>Games controls.</summary>
            GAME = 0x05,
            /// <summary>Keyboard controls.</summary>
            KEYBOARD = 0x07,
        }

        public enum HidUsage : ushort
        {
            /// <summary>Unknown usage.</summary>
            Undefined = 0x00,
            /// <summary>Pointer</summary>
            Pointer = 0x01,
            /// <summary>Mouse</summary>
            Mouse = 0x02,
            /// <summary>Joystick</summary>
            Joystick = 0x04,
            /// <summary>Game Pad</summary>
            Gamepad = 0x05,
            /// <summary>Keyboard</summary>
            Keyboard = 0x06,
            /// <summary>Keypad</summary>
            Keypad = 0x07,
            /// <summary>Muilt-axis Controller</summary>
            SystemControl = 0x80,
            /// <summary>Tablet PC controls</summary>
            Tablet = 0x80,
            /// <summary>Consumer</summary>
            Consumer = 0x0C,
        }
```

That device - card scanner, is HID that emulating keyboard in system. All works but I have problem: messages from device goes no only for my app (that works in the background, in the tray) but to active window app too. How I can disable that and set message available only for my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I spend a lot of time to solve that problem and here are results and illustration for it:
[image: Keyboard message path in Windows]

1. I can't use Raw Input because on this level message already reached all applications that register that device for input data as my.
2. I can't use low level keyboard hooks because WinAPI provides no information about device in hook. Yes, that's unbelievable, but design of that API is so bad.
3. The only way (I'm sure of it) is to use kernel modules. If you need to solve that problem, you can write it yourself or use this [library](http://oblita.com/interception.html) on C++. It works perfect, have very good get started on english and solved my problem. Yes, it is no C# but it is not problem for me. If you need it on C# try to use this code in managable C++.

Answer (score 1):

Raw Input does not support what you are asking for.  Multiple apps are allowed to register for the same device, there is no option to gain exclusive access.  You would have to use `SetWindowsHookEx()` to intercept and discard `WM_INPUT` messages, and `WM_KEY...` related messages (assuming the other apps are not using the `RIDEV_NOLEGACY` flag), that are not directed at your window.

Comment: Thank you. But now I have another problem - I cant detect is that keyboard or card-scanner that emulating keyboard. I cant get device name from hook function and can't block message from raw input. What can I do? :(

Comment: This is what happens when you use a device that emulates something else. Even the OS does not know the difference. The whole point of Raw Input is that you are getting messages from the device itself. So there is very little, if anything, that you *CAN* do to solve your original problem.

Comment: That being said, typically a barcode scanner that generates keystroke messages will send special characters before/after the scanned data so apps know when scanning begins/ends. You might see if your card scanner is doing something similar. See this artivle for a barcode scanner written in C# using Raw Input: [Distinguishing Barcode Scanners from the Keyboard in WinForms](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/02/distinguishing-barcode-scanners-from-the-keyboard-in-winforms/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable other apps from also registering for Raw Input (without using hooks etc).

But you can prevent normal keyboard messages being generated to the foregrond window using the `NOLEGACY` flag.

```cs
rid[0].Flags = RawInputDeviceFlags.INPUTSINK | RawInputDeviceFlags.NOLEGACY;
```